# Passing/converting a std::function taking less parameters than destination type

Tags: c++, function, lambda, functional-programming

Sometimes, you need to convert a std::function of a given type, to a std::function taking more parameters (but with same return type and first parameters)

For instance:

```
std::function<double(double)> A;
std::function<double()> B = [](){ return 3.14159; };

A = B; //Doesn't compile
A = [B](double){ return B(); }; //Compiles
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, which wouldn't require more memory and calls than below?

```
A = [](double){ return 3.14159; };
```

Comment: The advantage of the lambda is of course that you can choose which parameters you want: `auto bar = [&foo](double a, double, double c) { return foo(a,c); };`.

Comment: I suspect the real problem would be non-trivial types in the argument list. Consider `double(std::string)`, especially when calling `A("")`. There's no way that `std::function` is going to beat `auto A = [](std::string) { return 3.1415; }`. The latter lambda is going to be inlined.

Comment: You could copy your implementations `std::function`, and add in bits to drop the extra args

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar issue, then I found the following solution with using `std::bind`:

```
std::function<double(double)> A;
std::function<double()> B = [](){ return 3.14159; };

A = B; //Doesn't compile
A = std::bind(B); //Compiles
```

I'm not sure if it provides the same performance, but I don't see any reason why it should be slower.